ASP.NET Core SignalR over Azure Hybrid Connection
I've got issues with getting ASP.NET Core SignalR to work over Azure Hybrid Connection and hope someone can help.
What is
On-premise (required) service which runs a local webserver providing a REST API and SignalR hubs to the local network
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options => options.Listen(...));

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build(); 

app.MapHub<IHubImplementation>("[PATH]");


separately a different webserver using Azure Relay to provide certain REST API endpoints to a mobile application over Hybrid Connections
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder()
    .UseAzureRelay(options => options.UrlPrefixes.Add(...));

providing the possibility to re-use controller implementations of the local server.
Goal
Provide an existing SignalR hub to the mobile application using the Azure Relay.
So far

Add SignalR to the relay web-app and map hubs like for the local webserver instance:
Seems not to work since the connection gets refused with following StatusCode 400 This service does not support WebSocket connections.

Azure SignalR Service:
By using the Azure SignalR Service, it would be necessary to either create service endpoints for each installation (unmanageable) or provide custom client-negotiation and connection-management somewhere in the cloud (e.g. using Azure Function). Custom management in an Azure Function still concerns me regarding having to maintain application-related logic in a cloud function.

HybridConnectionListener
Implement a custom hybrid-connection handling on-premise, like shown in the PortPridge example provided by Azure on GitHub. However, being able to use the current REST API and SignalR hub implementation seems to be tricky. AFAIK it would be necessary to implement a HybridConnection Reverse Proxy to forward incoming requests to the webserver on one side and additionally also a websocket/stream passthrough for the SignalR feature-set (not even sure if feasible).


Question(s)

Is there a simple way to provide ASP.NET Core SignalR hubs (on-premise) by using the ASP.NET Core WebApplication/WebApplicationBuilder?
Would using the HybridConnectionListener mentioned above generally be a viable approach?
If so, is there a simple way to passthrough traffic (HTTP requests, WebSocket,...) from incoming connection to the local webserver?

I do not know if I'm missing something or making things more complicated than they have to be.
That said, I would really appreciate any idea, suggestion or help, thanks.

Can you share more details about how mobile clients connect and authenticate to the system?

Clients get authenticated in a cloud-service (independent from the on-premise application) using MFA, receive a SAS token and the HybridConnection endpoint address, then simply make HTTP requests to the currently available (on-premise) REST API using the HybridConnection.
